# Discontinous lines of contour plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to plot a graph using contour plot as below, but the lines are not smooth as they should be, how can I fix that?

```
r5 = ImplicitRegion[-Pi <= y + x <= Pi && -Pi <= y - x <= Pi && 
   y <= Pi && y >= -Pi, {x, y}]

    p3 = Show @@ 
  Table[ContourPlot[
    a == (Tan[(y - x)/2] + Tan[(y + x)/2])/2, {x, y} \[Element] r5, 
    ContourStyle -> Black], {a, -4, 4, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: I get smooth contours (V13.1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmbdu.png

Comment: You could use, for instance, `ContourPlot[..., Contours -> Range[-8, 8, 1/2]]` to speed up the valuation as an additional suggestion.

Comment: In any case, smoothness may be controlled with the options `PlotPoints` (default 15) and `MaxRecursion` (default 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also use `Contours` and `RegionFunction` instead.

```
ContourPlot[(Tan[(y - x)/2] + Tan[(y + x)/2])/2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
  3}, Contours -> Range[-4, 4, .3], ContourShading -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, -Pi <= y + x <= Pi && -Pi <= y - x <= Pi && 
    y <= Pi && y >= -Pi]]
```

[image]